# how to rename multiple files by keeping only the 12 first caracters ubuntu

Tags: ubuntu

I have thousands of file in my ubuntu 18 VM with the same number of caracters

I want to rename all those files by keeping only the 12 first caracters

for exemple, I want to rename abcdefghijklmnop in abcdefghijkl

I have tried this command `for i in *; do mv "$i" "${i% | cut -c1-12}"; done`

but none of them were renamed. The terminal is saying that these "are the same file"

What can command should I use ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
for i in *; do mv "$i" "$(echo $i | cut -c1-12)"; done
```

I would also not rely on `for` but use `while` loop to read the whole line, which might contain spaces (and `for` will divide those to separate lines and break):

```
ls * |while read i; do mv "$i" "$(echo $i | cut -c1-12)"; done
```

Comment: what will happend if have a file named abcdefghijkl1 and an other file named abcdefghijkl2 ? Is it possible to order the way the loop is reading my files ?

Comment: The second will overwrite the first. You did not mention in your question that you need to do checks, only asked how to rename the files :) You can incorporate checks if the file already exists with that name, and if it does, you can append something appropriate, and check again..